# Angular, Binding doesn't work when use Promise.catch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I use Auth0 for signin and I have the following code:

```
$scope.login = function () {
        $scope.loginFailed = false;
        $scope.loading = true;

        loaderService.show();

        let credentials = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        };
        principal.signin(credentials)
            .then(() => {
                $state.go('main.index');
            })
            .catch(e => {
                showError(e.error_description);
                loaderService.hide();
            });
    };
```

The `principle` service contains signin function:

```
signin(credentials) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.auth.signin({
                connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
                email: credentials.email,
                sso: false,
                password: credentials.password,
                authParams: {
                    scope: 'openid name email'
                }
            }, this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this, resolve, reject), this.onLoginFailed.bind(this, reject));
        });
    }
```

So, as you can see I create promise and pass resolve/reject to Auth0 callbacks.
Callbacks are pretty simple:

```
onLoginSuccess(resolve, reject, profile, token) {
        let userData = this.collectData(profile);
        ... store token
        return this.syncCurrent(userData) //request to server
            .then(() => {
                return resolve();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.signOut();
                return reject();
            });
}

onLoginFailed(reject, error) {
        return reject(error.details);
}
```

So, let's return to the first snippet. There are the following code:

```
principal.signin(credentials)
                .then(() => {
                    $state.go('main.index');
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    showError(e.error_description);
                    loaderService.hide();
                });
```

When I use correct email/password redirect works fine and I see main page. But when I use wrong email/password I see that `catch` block is executed, I see that values are changed in the debugger, but I don't see error block and loading image is not disappered. This is not problem in html, because I am refactoring code now, and all the code above was in one file and I didn't use promises and all worked fine. I tried to execute `showError` method before `principal.signin(credentials)` function, just for test, and I saw error and loading image was hidden. So, I think the problem is with promises and catch block exactly, but I don't know where.

PS. The `showError` is the following:

```
function showError(errorText) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.loginFailed = true;
        $scope.loginErrorMessage = errorText;
    }
```

Comment: I strongly believe the cause is using non-Angular promises in `signin()`. Angular promises ($q) are special because they invoke the digest cycle. If you have to use the external `Promise`, call `$apply()` on an available scope (e.g. the `$rootScope`).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos just tried `$apply` and I see error in html now, but  loading image is still visible. I will try to rewrite to `q` promises and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Yes, you are right. All works fine with `$q`. Thanks, again. Could you create answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is using non-Angular promises. Angular promises, i.e. the `$q` service, take care of invoking the digest cycle after they are resolved. The digest cycle is the implementation of change detection in Angular 1, i.e. what notifies watchers and enables actions to take place.

Using `$q` solves this problem.

The `then` part of your code probably worked because it called `$state.go()` which in turn invokes the digest cycle. The `catch` part did not, so the changes never got a chance to fire the watchers.